# ebay query into mysql?

Tags: mysql

I would like to know if it is possible,

To extract the userid from an ebay page and insert it into mysql as part of an insert statement? Otherwise what would be the best way to do this?

I have files to import, which contain hundred of ebay auction urls, and I must grab the seller id from each one. Is there an easier way to do this than what I am suggesting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [eBay API](http://developer.ebay.com/common/api/) for that.  The URL for each page contains an item number, and that can be used to query eBay for the seller id.

[eBay Hacks Item 109](http://books.google.com/books?id=bIMY8x-dpTMC&pg=PA391&lpg=PA391&dq=ebay+api+get+seller+id&source=web&ots=cv3mDqGq5w&sig=1l-5j7hXytPEZl-rDebdcQKKPrk&hl=en&sa=X&oi=book_result&resnum=9&ct=result) gives some PHP example code to do what you need (and more).

Comment: I was trying to avoid using the ebay API, as I do not want to have to write a separate program to do this before importing.

Comment: Without the API you'd have to write a bit of code that downloads and parses the auction page. I'd say using the API will be as easy, if not easier. And you won't get into troube when eBay changes the page layout in some way.

Comment: I agree with Lasar.  If an API is available, you want to avoid scraping the page.

Comment: OK, thanks guys. Is there a sample of a function to do exactly what I want, i.e. obtain a seller id from an auction number? I am not a programmer as such and need this for a database thing.

Comment: There's some example code in eBay Hacks.  See my edited reply.

Comment: @bill  was wondering if you can help out wtih this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929259/ebay-api-returning-auctions-ending-later-than-10-days